# Bash add SFTP user, home directory, and chmod it

Tags: bash

So i've gotten this far, but it doesn't work. it says

```
Changing directory to /var/www/sftp...
: No such file or directoryar/www/sftp
Making user directory...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘luna\r’: File exists
Making public_html directory...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘public_html\r’: File exists
Copying preset index...
cp: cannot stat '../../index.html': No such file or directory
chmoding public_html directory...
```

Now for the code, i've written...

```
echo Changing directory to /var/www/sftp...
cd /var/www/sftp
echo Making user directory...
mkdir $1
cd $1
echo Making public_html directory...
mkdir public_html
cd public_html
echo Copying preset index...
cp ../../index.html ./index.html
echo chmoding public_html directory...
chmod 777 ../public_html
```

For the output i included the second version because it creates the directory "luna\r" not "luna". Also the echo before the cd was an attempt to fix the issue with cd where for whatever reason it's trying to change directory to "ar/www/sftp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has DOS line endings (carriage return / line feed, also known as CR/LF or 0x0D 0x0A). It will probably work much better if you use unix line endings (line feed only).

Comment: Sorry. Linux noob here. How do i do that?